# glibc detected malloc(): memory corruption in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, glibc, memory-corruption

I am trying to compile and code written in C under linux, and got this error message:

> glibc detected  malloc(): memory corruption

and I cannot find out why...

the substring() just return you part of the original string by giving the starting index and length.  e.g. substring("this is example",0,4) = "this";

```
char *substring(char* str, int start, int length) {
    char *newString = (char *)malloc(length * sizeof(char));
    int i, x = 0;
    int end=start+length-1;
    for(i = start ; i <= end; i++){
        newString[x++] = str[i];
    }
    newString[x] = '\0';
    return newString;
}
```

and the getCharIndexFirst() just returns the index of first occurance of the specified char
the getCharIndexLast() just returns the index of last occurance of the specified char

and below is the main function:

```
//consoleCommand has the form of 'send MESSAGE ID', has the value from stdin

int firstSpace = getCharIndexFirst(consoleCommand,' ');
int lastSpace = getCharIndexLast(consoleCommand,' ');
int len = strlen(consoleCommand);

char *header = substring(consoleCommand,0,firstSpace);
printf("header is: %s\n",header);
char *cmd = substring(consoleCommand,firstSpace+1,lastSpace-firstSpace-1);
printf("command is: %s\n",cmd); // the code only runs up to here and output the error..
char *socketstr = substring(consoleCommand,lastSpace+1,len-lastSpace-1);
printf("socket is: %s\n",socketstr);
```

**Here is more info: the consoleCommand is usually the stdin, has the form of 'send MESSAGE ID', the error occurs when the MESSAGE is 12 char long...
e.g. 'send this message 4', 'this message' is the cmd and has length of 12 chars, this gives me error! 
and it works fine for any other lengths, i have tried 3, 4, 24...**

Any hint will be appreciated, THANKS!

Comment: Learn to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and compile with all warnings & debug ingo (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). Use the `gdb` debugger.

Answer (score 13):

```
newString[x] = '\0';
```

At this point `x` is equal to `length`, which means you're writing 1 character beyond the end of the memory you allocated. You need to allocate space for one more character.

Answer (score 5):

You don't allocate any space for the terminating `'\0'` character, so you overflow your allocation to write this character.  You need to count this character in your allocation too:

```
char *newString = (char *)malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

Comment: @HughH sizeof(char) == 1 and is pointless. *The* tool to find this kind of a bug is Valgrind -- it would point you straight at the bug.

Comment: If you're on an arm machine, especially arm64, Valgrind isn't up to date enough, since it tries to know every opcode.  3.13 knows arm but not arm64.  GDB often gives nonsense on a backtrace, even compiling with -g.  And it's not safe in the age of unicode and wide characters to assume sizeof(char) is always 1.  But yeah, you always need 1 byte for the terminating '\0'.

Comment: @AlanCorey char is mandated to be a single byte by the standard. Unicode has nothing to do with it.