# Why does buffer overflow occur without address sanitizer?

Tags: gcc, buffer-overflow, address-sanitizer

This may a question like a newbie.

If a C program compiled with address sanitizer then Heap Buffer Overflow easily detected.
However, I've observed some C programs (I cannot remember exactly what it is, sorry..) occur heap buffer overflow even if they compiled without address sanitizer.

To my knowledge, GCC does not check memory boundaries, but how does HBO occur without address sanitizer?

Can I get your advice or point out my misunderstanding?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you give any example of that situation and the compiling command?

Comment: `occur heap buffer overflow` What does "occur" exactly? How do you _observe_ a heap buffer overflow? Why an "address sanitizer" would protect against it?

Comment: I'm guessing he means something like [glibc detected malloc(): memory corruption](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19057079/1983398).

Comment: @KamilCuk Sorry to confuse.
I mean a program *crash* due to the HBO

Comment: Now you confused a little bit more. _Nothing_ will prevent a _crash_, you can always write to invalid memory `int main() { char *a = malloc(1); a[100]=1; }`. What do you mean by "how does HBO occur without address sanitizer"? How does HBO occur _with_ an adderss sanitizer and why do you expect a difference?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does buffer overflow occur without address sanitizer?

You are probably using the word "occur" incorrectly.

The heap buffer overflow *happens* (occurs) because there is a bug in your program, and it happens *regardless* of whether the program is instrumented with address sanitizer or not, whether it runs under Valgrind or not, etc.

Your question is likely "how can the heap buffer overflow be *detected* without address sanitizer"?

And an answer to that is that there are multiple techniques, many predate invention of the address sanitizer by decades.

Excluding address sanitizer, and ordering from most to least powerful:

- running under Valgrind can detect all heap buffer overflows and underflows,
- using Electric Fence can detect all heap buffer overflows (but with a huge increase in total memory usage). EFence can also detect underflows, but not at the same time as overflows,
- using debugging memory allocator, it is possible to add a "red zone" before / after each allocation, fill these red zones with a known bit pattern, and periodically check that the pattern is still intact. This allows for catching of *some* overflows, and only *after* the overflow has happened, but usually not exactly when it happens,
- finally, the default GLIBC heap allocator can detect some forms of heap overflow by observing that its own internal structures are corrupt,